# Apply Discount to Grouped Product

Tags: magento2, discount, grouped-products

I want to apply discount on the grouped products. The associated products are visible, so when i use cart price rule, the discount is applicable to them as well.
Please suggest me an alternate way to do it.
We can't create duplicate product and use them instead because of inventory reasons.